# How to show current and previous 6 Months with Year in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nscalendar

I am working in a project where I need to show current and previous 6 months with year. I am using below code to do this.

```
for (int i=0; i< numberofMonths; i++) {

    NSString *index=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i+1];

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [NSDateComponents new];
    comps.month = - (i+1);
    NSDate *date = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:date]; // Get necessary date 


    currentYear  = [components year];
    currentmonth=[components month];
    yearstring = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%ld",currentYear];
    yearstring=[yearstring substringFromIndex:MAX((int)[yearstring length]-2, 0)];
    monthName = [[df monthSymbols] objectAtIndex:(currentmonth-1 )];
    NSString *string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",monthName,yearstring];
    }
```

This code works fine for all months. But when I set the current month as January/February. Then it does gives error of array range.
Please advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that when you call `[[df monthSymbols] objectAtIndex:(currentmonth-1 )];` for currentMonth of 1 then you end up with an invalid month number.  Much simpler code to achieve what you are after is -

```
int numberOfMonths=6;

NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM, YY" ];

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDate *now=[NSDate date];

NSDateComponents *comps = [NSDateComponents new];

for (int i=-numberOfMonths; i< 1; i++) {

    comps.month = i;
    NSDate *newDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:now options:0];

    NSString *string=[formatter stringFromDate:newDate];
    NSLog(@"date=%@",string);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NSDateFormatter` to get the year&month string from the `NSDate`. No need to do all these circus. Check my code, is this what do you want?

```
  for (int i=0; i< 6; i++) {

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [NSDateComponents new];
    comps.month = - (i+1);
    NSDate *date = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:date]; // Get necessary date

    NSDateFormatter *df = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [df setDateFormat:@"MMMM, yy"];
    NSString *dateString = [df stringFromDate:date];
        NSLog(@"%@ ",dateString);
}
```